# How to make animated notch bottom bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, navbar, flutter-animation, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm looking for this kind of animation in flutter: https://dribbble.com/shots/4844696-Tab-bar-interaction-with-animated-icons

Original React native solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mindinventory/react-native-tab-bar-interaction

Does anyone have tips for making this type of animation?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9M41.png)

I'm using this package for bottom navbar :https://pub.dev/packages/circle_nav_bar

If you know a better navbar package, please let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

For your animated solution please try this flutter pub plugin . this will give the same effect.
https://pub.dev/packages/animated_notch_bottom_bar/example